# How to properly set ImageSize for both presentation mode and printout?

Tags: plotting, slideshows

I made some slide presentations for teaching using Mathematica 12.0. It works reasonably well as shown in the following screenshot
[image]
The plot in the screenshot is set to have `ImageSize->Large`.

However, when I save a presentation notebook as PDF file to send to students, the plot becomes really huge comparing to the text, as shown below.

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to set `ImageSize` so that in both cases the plot would have a reasonable size.

Update:

If I set `ImageSize->Scaled[0.4]`, then some how the plot labels become far away from the plot.

[image]

Comment: You can try `ImageSize->Scaled[0.6(*your preferable size here*)]` and see if it works for you.